# Questions regarding usb cameras

Tags: ros, libuvc-camera, camera, usb-cam, uvc-camera

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm new to ROS as well as to linux and has been trying to get the usb camera to work.

I've followed the tutorials from:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/InstallingandConfiguringROSEnvironment
and
http://www.ros.org/wiki/ROS/Tutorials/StackInstallation
and
http://www.iheartrobotics.com/2010/05/vision-for-robots-1-of-n-setup.html

but I'm still unable to install it properly. When i try to enter the command
$rosmake --rosdep-install
I get the error "No package or stack specified.  And current directory 'usb_cam' is not a package name or stack name."

Can someone help me? thanks in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/29918/questions-regarding-usb-cameras/) by [Sinjon](https://answers.ros.org/users/1827/sinjon/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2012-03-17

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

If you can deal with the code being GPL, you may want to try using this driver
http://www.ros.org/wiki/uvc_camera

The tutorials will be updated after Fuerte is released hopefully.

---

Originally posted by [I Heart Robotics](https://answers.ros.org/users/15/i-heart-robotics/) with karma: 403 on 2012-03-17

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-18**:
The only caveat is the USB camera has to support USB Video Class (UVC). It seems a lot of them do, but not everything ... for example the camera in my MacBook.

**Comment by [Ken](https://answers.ros.org/users/13/ken/) on 2012-03-18**:
uvc_camera uses video4linux, so it should work with most of the non-UVC cameras that v4l supports. Support for non-UVC cameras is probably going to be moved into a separate node when uvc_camera is replaced with a cross-platform, UVC-only version.

**Comment by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) on 2012-03-18**:
Ah ... I am confused. I was referring to [libuvc_ros](https://github.com/ktossell/libuvc_ros) (which does work on my macbook, just not with the built in camera) and got confused with uvc_camera (which I guess uses v4l).

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You can also try [libuvc_ros](http://www.ros.org/wiki/libuvc_camera). It works pretty good with Logitech cameras on my MacBook.

---

Originally posted by [Kevin](https://answers.ros.org/users/186/kevin/) with karma: 2962 on 2012-03-18

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1